# Is there a term to define the influence and sharing of common expressions among people?

Tags: terminology

I'm wondering how to call the phenomenon that happens when people spend a lot of time together and end up sharing similar vocabulary or reusing the other's expressions? Is there a term for this?

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be referring to *mimicry* or *linguistic mimicry*. Mimicry is more broad than just vocabulary and expressions, but the general principle of imitating what others in a social group are doing applies.

Comment: This was not exactly what I was looking for but allowed me to find what I needed - The Chameleon Effect. Thank you!